# Curses exception when drawing to (24, 79)

Tags: c++, curses

I noticed a very curious bug. When I use windows (`Curses.StdScr` or a new `Window`), I get an exception when trying to draw to the very last screen position (y=24, x=79):

`mvwaddnwstr() returned ERR`

The code is:

`w.Add(y, x, r)` where `y=24`, `x=79`, and `r='!'`

Some weird facts:

- If I neglect this position, I can draw to every other position in the screen.
- If I call `w.Box()`, it draws the border fine
- If I catch and eat the exception for that position, it draws fine

It seems like a bug.  Is this a known bug or does it have a known work-around? Eating the exception cuts my FPS in half.

I've seen this in CursesSharp (C#), Ruby (ncurses), and the Python Curses wrapper.